# Mysql: How to correctly generate a unique 10-digit random number that does not exist on the current set of numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have this query:

```
select t1.newval from 
(select LPAD(FLOOR(10000000000*RAND()), 10, '0') as 'newval') as t1 
where t1.newval not in (select unqiue_no from table)
```

Note: the query works fine however the test is not extensive since my data is limited and the length is 10 digits.

I'm not sure if this query will never collide with the existing numbers.
Since this query does not loop.

Is there any possibility that it will return an empty value if the newval number collides with the existing uqnique numbers?

Thanks in advance for your insights.

Edited to format mysql

Comment: I tested the query on a small table with small data. I'm generating 2digits only of random number. Upon collision, result will give you an empty set.

Comment: One way is to remove a random row from another large data set

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a chance.

Initially that chance would be extremely low:, 1 in 10 billion. With every allocated key, the odds increase, but the odds of a collision are still extremely low ... 1 in 10billion - (# of previously allocated numbers).

Regardless, there will always be a chance because that is how you designed the query -- requiring it to query against the table of allocated id's, just in case.

I am going to assume here, that what you need is a key.  If that is the case, you would be best off generating the number and attempting to INSERT (assuming you are using this number as a primary key) and building in recovery from a duplicate key violation, rather than selecting against an ever increasing data set of allocated keys.

The more immediate concern is not whether you will get an empty result set, but rather the speed of the query which requires a query of the table of existing keys, and as that becomes large, will slow the query down in a predictable manner.  As you already are banking on that being an event that is very low in probability, I don't see the value in that subquery.